# Django child inherited object can't see M2M parent attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, m2m, django-inheritance

I have the following models:

```
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

        class Entity(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=64) 
            desc = models.TextField('Description',)
            tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name='companies')
            sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)

    class Company(Entity):  
        founded_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Enter in YYYY-MM-DD format.')
        employee_amount = models.IntegerField('Number of Employees',blank=True, null=True)

class Employee(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    entity = models.ForeignKey('companies.Entity', blank=True, null=True)
```

I am trying to save the company for the first time (add) and update (edit).

I am doing that in my view with:

```
try:
            company = Company.objects.get(employee=get_employee(request.user))
            form = CompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=company)
        except:
            form = CompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)


        if form.is_valid():
            company  = form.save(commit=False)

            if action == 'add':
                try:
                    entity = Entity.objects.get(name=company.name)
                    company = entity.company
                    employee.entity = entity
                    employee.save()
                except:
                    pass

            company.save()
            employee.entity = company
            employee.save()
            employee.entity.sites.add(current_site)
            company.save_m2m()
```

When I do this I get the error:

> 'Company' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

How can this be when the parent "Entity" has this value and the child "Company" should have access to it?

Answer (score 1):

`save_m2m` must be called on the form, not on a model instance (see [this topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/)).